# Dynamically hide/show radio buttons in rails form doesn't hide when unchecked

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, form-for

I need to dynamically show/hide a list of radio buttons in my rails form when the "Daily" radio button is checked.  This almost works, except that when I check "Weekly" (which unchecks "Daily"), the list does not hide.  New to javascript and trying to figure out what I'm missing.

```
<%= form_for list_chores_path(@list.id) do |f| %>
 <div class="field">
   <%= f.radio_button :frequency, 'Daily', onClick: "resetradio(this)" %> Daily<br>
   <div class="buttons" style="display:none;">
       <%= f.radio_button :time_of_day, 'Morning', onClick:"setradio()" %> Morning<br>
   <%= f.radio_button :time_of_day, 'Evening', onClick:"setradio()" %> Evening<br>
   <%= f.radio_button :time_of_day, 'Any Time', onClick:"setradio()" %> Any Time<br>
   </div>
   <%= f.radio_button :frequency, 'Weekly' %> Weekly<br>
 </div>


 <script type="text/javascript">
   function resetradio (radio) {
   var buttons = document.querySelector('.buttons');
   var radios = document.getElementsByName('/lists/<%= @list.id %>/chores[time_of_day]');
   radios[0].checked = false;
   if (radio.checked == true) {
      buttons.style.display = 'block';
          }
   else {
      buttons.style.display = 'none';
          }
    }

    function setradio () {
     var radio = document.getElementsByName('/lists/<%= @list.id %>/chores[frequency]')[0];
      if (radio.checked == false) {
          radio.checked = true;      
          }
      }
   </script>
```

Here is the HTML

```
<div class="field">
   <input onclick="resetradio(this)" type="radio" value="Daily" name="/lists/4/chores[frequency]" id="_lists_4_chores_frequency_daily"> Daily<br>
   <div class="buttons" style="display: block;">
       <input onclick="setradio()" type="radio" value="Morning" name="/lists/4/chores[time_of_day]" id="_lists_4_chores_time_of_day_morning"> Morning<br>
       <input onclick="setradio()" type="radio" value="Evening" name="/lists/4/chores[time_of_day]" id="_lists_4_chores_time_of_day_evening"> Evening<br>
       <input onclick="setradio()" type="radio" value="Any Time" name="/lists/4/chores[time_of_day]" id="_lists_4_chores_time_of_day_any_time"> Any Time<br>
   </div>
   <input type="radio" value="Weekly" name="/lists/4/chores[frequency]" id="_lists_4_chores_frequency_weekly"> Weekly<br>
```

Comment: There's no such thing as `document.getElementsById`, since an `id` is supposed to unique. *Always* check your browser console for errors first.

Comment: Thanks for the tip!  I changed it to "document.getElementsByName" and no longer get an error.  Unfortunately, I am still getting the same behavior where the time_of_day radio buttons are not hiding when "Daily" is unchecked.

Comment: Can you edit your Q so it shows the actual HTML output, as opposed to the ror source?

Comment: Your source looks like you're generating the entire code multiple times? As in that entire snippet is inside the for loop? Including the `<script>` part? That's a bad idea.

Comment: That is a good point.  I pulled it out.

Answer (score 0):

It is because when you click weekly you don't call the javascript function -  resetradio(this).
Following should work

```
<%= f.radio_button :frequency, 'Weekly', onClick: "resetradio(this)" %> Weekly<br>
```

Comment: This successfully cleared the time_of_day radio buttons.  I ended up creating a radio variable in the resetradio() function instead of passing in "this", and both changes worked.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by adding an Onclick to Weekly (Thanks Shani!), and then creating a radio variable in the resetradio() function instead of passing "this" into it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function resetradio () {
      var radio = document.getElementsByName('/lists/<%= @list.id %>/chores[frequency]')[0];
      var buttons = document.querySelector('.buttons');
      var radios = document.getElementsByName('/lists/<%= @list.id %>/chores[time_of_day]');
      radios[0].checked = false;
      if (radio.checked == true) {
      buttons.style.display = 'block';
  }
  else {
      buttons.style.display = 'none';
  }
}



function setradio () {
  var radio = document.getElementsByName('/lists/<%= @list.id %>/chores[frequency]')[0];
  if (radio.checked == false) {
      radio.checked = true;

      } 
  }
</script>
```